# How do I create two self-contained libraries from one webpack config?

Tags: webpack

My environment uses Laravel mix. I'm using CommonsChunkPlugin to extract node_modules into vendor.js, and I use imports to generate several late-load modules.

Now I want to add a set of IE 11 polyfills, which will only be loaded in IE 11. CommonsChunkPlugin isn't working for me, because either the polyfill and all of its dependencies are in polyfill.js, or all of the shared dependencies are in vendor.js. I would like to duplicate the dependencies, so that the polyfill is self-contained -- polyfill.js and vendor.js should each include all of their dependencies, even if there's overlap.

My Laravel mix config looks kind of like this:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const webpack = require('webpack');

let webpackConfig = {
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'js/vendor',
            minChunks: function(module) {
                if (module.resource) {
                    if (/whatwg-fetch|babel-polyfill/.test(module.resource)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return /node_modules/.test(module.context);
            }
        }),

        // This doesn't work, because most of babel-polyfill is dependencies. Only the base file is extracted from vendor.
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'js/iePolyfill',
            minChunks: function(module) {
                return /node_modules\/babel-polyfill|whatwg-fetch/.test(module.context);
            }
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'js/manifest',
            minChunks: Infinity
        })
    ],
};

mix
    .webpackConfig(webpackConfig)
    .react('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js');
```

I import this file from the main entrypoint (assets/js/app.js)

```
import 'babel-polyfill';
import 'whatwg-fetch';
```

I've also tried not importing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. CommonsChunkPlugin was building vendor.js as the overlapping node_modules component of the two entries (app.js and iePolyfills.js). I fixed this by:

- Using the "chunks" property of CommonsChunkPlugin to override the default behavior.
- Creating my own "entry" webpack config to override the behavior of Laravel Mix.
- I also had to add "module" configuration, because I could no longer use the Laravel Mix .react() shortcut.

Here's the corrected config:

```
    const mix = require('laravel-mix');
    const webpack = require('webpack');

    let webpackConfig = {
        entry: {
            iePolyfill: './resources/assets/js/iePolyfill.js',
            app: './resources/assets/js/app.js',
        },
        output: {
            filename: 'js/[name].js'
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
                name: 'js/vendor',
                chunks: ['app'],
                minChunks: function(module) {
                    return /node_modules/.test(module.context);
                }
            }),
            new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
                name: 'js/manifest',
                minChunks: Infinity
            })
        ],
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                    use: "babel-loader",
                    exclude: /node_modules/
                }
            ],
            loaders: [
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    loader: 'babel',
                    query: {
                        presets: ['es2015','react']
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    };

    mix.webpackConfig(webpackConfig);
```